# Mysql Fatal error encountered during command execution

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, mysql-error-1064

I got the following error while calling a stored procedure in asp.net c#page. I could not understand the error details. Please help me to solve this.

```
MySqlCommand cmd =
    new MySqlCommand("CALL sp_wrt_test(10, @param);SELECT @param", connection);

cmd.CommandTimeout = 5000000;

//Assign the query using CommandType7
using (IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    if (reader.Read())
        id = "@param = " + reader[0];
}


create procedure sp_wrt_test(in name varchar(100), out retval varchar(200))
begin
 insert into hd_test(fld_name) values(name);
 select max(fld_id)into retval from hd_test;
end;
```

Comment: You never declare `@param` what is it?  An output variable?  Even so you still need to add it to the command.  Please post the exact error message you are getting.  Also Grant is right, the CALL then SELECT looks odd.

Comment: http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/Parameters.html Look this.

Comment: OK please post the error message *and* the code for your stored procedure.

Comment: The above question is my error. Please see my edited post for procedure.

Comment: I don't see an error message, and you seem to be calling MySqlCommand before it has it's @param value.  Also, I don't understand the second part of your call - SELECT @param".  Are you looking for retval?

Comment: Now i change my code like this.  MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("CALL sp_wrt_test(?val, @param);", connection);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?val", "admbsa1");
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@param", SqlDbType.VarChar));
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        string t_return = cmd.Parameters["@param"].Value.ToString();

Comment: I got an another error OUT or INOUT argument 2 for routine sp_wrt_test is not a variable or NEW pseudo-variable in BEFORE trigger